# JSF 1.2 on Wildfly and beforePhaseListener

Tags: java, jsf

I'm try to run my App JSF 1.2 on WildFly but my attribut beforePhaseListener in my view tag doesn't work. I install all lib for JSF 1.2 on wildfly and in my Web.XML I have this value :

```xml
<context-param>  
   <param-name>org.jboss.jbossfaces.JSF_CONFIG_NAME</param-name>  
   <param-value>mojarra-1.2</param-value>  
</context-param> .
```

In my Xhtml I have this :

```xml
f:view 
  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
  xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
  xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
  xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
  xmlns:a4j="http://richfaces.org/a4j"
  xmlns:rich="http://richfaces.org/rich"
  beforePhaseListener="#{myBean.beforePhase}"
```

and in myBean I have this method signature :

```java
public void beforePhase(PhaseEvent event)
```

but I always get this error :

> **The class 'myBean' does not have the property 'beforePhase'**.

Thank you